# threeofakind and fourofakind functions for yahtzee

Tags: javascript

My code for detecting and scoring threeOfAKind and fourOfAKind in my yahtzee game only works some of the time. If I input the array [5,1,1,1,1] into my fourOfAKind-loop the output in undefined, and i can't figure out why. Here is my code:

```
    //threeOfAKind
    if(nnb==3){
        for(i = 0; i < (dice.length - nnb); i++){
            if((dice[i] == dice[i+1]) 
            && (dice[i] == dice[i+2])){
                score = dice[i]*nnb;
            }
        }
    }
    //fourOfAKind
    else if(nnb==4){
        for(i = 0; i < (dice.length - nnb); i++){
            if((dice[i] == dice[i+1]) 
            && (dice[i] == dice[i+2])
            && (dice[i] == dice[i+3])){
                score = dice[i]*nnb;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your loops require the elements that are the same to be consecutive. Do you sort the array before you get here?

Comment: Your logic is flawed. First of all, shouldn't `dice.length` always be 5 in a yahtzee game? By limiting the loop to `i < (dice.length - nnb)`, your actually only executing it once, comparing the first dice value to the other ones, making a loop unnecessary. That's also why the case where the first dice value is different from the others is not taken into account.

Comment: What if your input is 1,5,1,5,1? Personally I'd use a different approach, unless you're implying your roll will be sorted before calling this. In any case, what do you mean by the "output is undefined"? There's no output anywhere.

Comment: Yes, the array is sorted in descending order first.

Comment: @DaveNewton OP's probably doing a `console.log(score)`, but as that variable is never initialized with a value and the if-condition in the loop is never met, it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of your loop is off by 1, it should be `dice.length - nnb + 1` or you can change the condition to `<=`. E.g. if you're looking for 3 of a kind, you need to check check the ranges starting from 0, 1, and 2; since `5-3 = 2`, you need to include `i = 2` in your loop.

Once you find that the condition is satisfied, you should break out of the loop.

```
    //threeOfAKind
    if(nnb==3){
        for(i = 0; i <= (dice.length - nnb); i++){
            if((dice[i] == dice[i+1]) 
            && (dice[i] == dice[i+2])){
                score = dice[i]*nnb;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //fourOfAKind
    else if(nnb==4){
        for(i = 0; i <= (dice.length - nnb); i++){
            if((dice[i] == dice[i+1]) 
            && (dice[i] == dice[i+2])
            && (dice[i] == dice[i+3])){
                score = dice[i]*nnb;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can generalize this to a single loop that works for any value of `nnb`, so you don't have to hard-code the indexes.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= dice.length - nnb; i++) {
    let first = dice[i];
    let matched = true;
    for (let j = 1; j < nnb; j++) {
        if (dice[i+j] != first) {
            matched = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (matched) {
        score = first * nnb;
        break;
    }
}
```